# Using org.json.simple package to send ajax response to Datatable plugin in JSP

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, servlets, datatables

I have been trying to get table values from MySQL database using servlet and convert that values to JSON using org.json.simple package.

When an ajax request is made from a JSP page on page loading which has DataTable javascript plugin in it, the values from JSON should be displayed in Datatable template.

But when the JSP page load it show error in alert as like this:

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

I am using Apache Tomcat version 10.0. Here I am sharing my JSP and servlet code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Book Status</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="images/logo.jpg" type ="image/x-icon">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="heading">
                <div class="title">
                    <h1><a href="index.jsp">Online Library</a></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="logo">
                    <i class="fas fa-book-reader fa-2x"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="BookIssue.jsp">Issue Books</a></li>
                <li><a href="addbooks.jsp">Add books</a></li>
                <li><a href="register.jsp">User Registration</a></li>
                <li><a href="Returnbook.jsp">Return Book</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <table id="example" class="display" style="width:50%"> //this is where the table appears
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Issue Id</th>
                    <th>User Id</th>
                    <th>Book Id</th>
                    <th>Genre</th>
                    <th>Issue Date</th>
                    <th>Return Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Issue Id</th>
                    <th>User Id</th>
                    <th>Book Id</th>
                    <th>Genre</th>
                    <th>Issue Date</th>
                    <th>Return Date</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <script>  //sending post request to servlet//
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "ajax":{
                    "url": "bookstatus",
                    "dataSrc": "data",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "dataType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                },columns:[
                {"data": "issueid"},
                {"data": "userid"},
                {"data": "bookid"},
                {"data": "genre"},
                {"data": "issuedate"},
                {"data": "returndate"}]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;

public class bookstatus extends HttpServlet {
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
throws ServletException, IOException { 
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    try{
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library","root","password");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from library.issue");
        JSONArray data=new JSONArray();
        JSONObject result=new JSONObject();
        while(rs.next()){
            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
            obj.put("issueid", rs.getString(1));
            obj.put("userid", rs.getString(2));
            obj.put("bookid", rs.getString(3));
            obj.put("genre", rs.getString(7));
            obj.put("issuedate", rs.getString(4));
            obj.put("returndate", rs.getString(5));
            data.add(obj);
            result.put("data", data);
        }
        out.println(result);   //this is the part I have a doubt whether this the right method or not 
        con.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you go through that [link](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1) page or not ?

Comment: _"Invalid JSON response"_ - What is the JSON response? You can show us by editing your question and providing the raw text data containing that JSON. Your browser tools (F12) will give you access to the data.

Comment: @Swati Yes mam It shows the page for resolving this error and it says that may be the ajax response doesn't return the valid response

Comment: @andrewjames In this I am not getting any response back, I checked in the network tab but it doesn't has any response from ajax call, sir.

Comment: Hi, this line `result.put("data", data);` should be outside your while loop . Currently on every iteration you are adding `data` inside `result` .

Comment: Also , try using `out.println(result.toString());` or `out.println(result.toJSONString())` .